# Printing Images

Tags: c#, printing

[image: Bubble Form]

I am trying to print this image using the following C# code:

```
        pd2.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pd2.OriginAtMargins = true;
        pd2.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;

        pd2.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
        {
            System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\6\\BubbleForm.tif");
            System.Drawing.Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

            if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
            {
                m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
            }
            else
            {
                m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
            }
            args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
        };

        pd2.Print();
```

Can this code (or any code) control any printer so that the location of the bubbles will be consistent across any printer?

Update:
The form is being printed, filled out and then scanned and processed by a third party software that is determining which of the bubbles has been marked.  To use the third party software a template is created which marks where the bubble locations are.  When this form was printed on  two different printers the location of the bubbles was different.   The code above was used to print to each printer.  Because the bubble locations came out differently, i am wondering if the code can provide consistent bubble location across any printer, or is the size or margins used specific to each printer and cannot be determined through the use of code?

Comment: that tif looks like it has the bubbles already on it. that is a "hard problem" that requires some image processing.

Comment: If you are just drawing the ready image, how __could__ the __bubbles__ move __within it__ in the first place??? Are talking about the size and/or the margins?

Comment: Based on your comment I have updated my question

Comment: OK, now it is clear. However I have to say that this is not your responsibilty. The scanning / processing softawre must detect the bubbles or some marker to calibrate it self. Acutually there ought to be 3 or 4 makers arounf the page so it can calculate the size and the angle.  The markes should be part of the orginal form imo. So offload the responsibilty where it belongs ;-) - Acutally I would expect the 3rd party software to do this right in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All printers will differ slightly in where they print something on a page because of slight variations in the feed mechanism, etc. What you need to do is find something on the page that you can recognise, after it's been scanned in, and use that to calibrate the software that knows where the bubbles are.

Ideally you want more than one artefact to use for calibration. For example, recognise the top left of the "Marking Instructions" box, and the bottom right of the parents/grandparents information at the bottom.

If you then know that a bubble is 70% of the horizontal distance between these two locations, and 30% of the vertical location, you can calculate exactly where on the scanned page it should be.

Make sense?

**EDIT:** Since you're on the printing side of the equation (as pointed out by +TaW, below), not the scanning side, the best thing you can do is add a '+' to each corner of the TIFF, outside the current printed area (but not outside the printable area, obviously), that whoever is doing the scanning side can identify and use for calibration as I've described above.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, except that he is no on the scanning/ processing side but on the printing side.

Comment: Bahaha - yes, you're dead right. I should have read more carefully.